# displaying some value to the active td class of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table in which when i click on a tr its class changes to active. In the td of the table i have an input field. Actually i want to display some stuffs in the active td of the table.

```
   $('#product').val(item['name']);
```

by this i can display my value to a div with id product. But how can i display this to the active td in my table.

```
<table id = "mytable">
 <tr>
    <td class = "active"><input type ="text" name="product[]" id="product"> </td>
    <td class = "active">some data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class=""><input type ="text" name="product[]" id="product"></td>
    <td class = "">some data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is my table. As i said this table is dynamic. that is why id is repeating.If it was a static table i can display my value to input field product  $('#product').val(item['name']). But when it changed to dynamic i wish to print the active tds value to the input field.
 But please help am stuck here.

Comment: Please provide relevant html sample per [mcve] and more details about how this should work

Comment: You said in the `td` you have an `input` field. Define the word `stuffs` you want to do?

Comment: You simply need to create a counter, then everytime you add a row make the `id= 'product' + counter`

Answer (score -1):

So when the td is focused you want to show some values in it ?
You can do that like this

```
$( "#td" ).focus(function() {
   $('#product').val(item['name']);
});
```